# C++ pointer output consistency

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to learn pointers in C++. I was running the following piece of code to see address and value in different pointers

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int x=10;
    int *p = &x; 

    char c2 = 'c';
    char *p2 = &c2;

    //cast to void pointer to see address in p2
    void *p3 = static_cast<void *>(p2); 

    cout<<"Address in p2/p3:"<< p3 <<endl;
    cout<<"Content of address in p2/p3:"<< *(static_cast<int *>(p3))<<endl;

}
```

In the last line, you can see that I am casting a void pointer into an int pointer. I was expecting junk values to be printed all the time I run the program. But to my surprise, it always printed 2659. I tried different online compilers, everywhere it printed 2659. 
I then tried removing the following 2 lines,

```
int x=10;
int *p = &x;
```

Then, it started printing junk values everytime i run. But pointer p3 is noway related to x and p. Can somebody explain what is happening here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Any reason for the output to be consistent when the p and x are there?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason: that's the way it works with your specific compiler and operating system. Objects in automatic scope turn out to be a specific layout on the stack, and, as such, the pointer ends up pointing to consistent memory contents. Note that 2659 is `0x00000a63` in hexadecimal. Your pointer ends up partially seeing the `0x0a` byte from your `x` variable. The the `0x63` part is the ASCII for lowercase `c`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The memory layout is such that 10 (little endian) is immediately followed by 'c' (ASCII 99) and 10 * 256 + 99 = 2659.

In many cases, UB is quite predictable behavior.

Comment: I understand your point. If you have some time, can you please explain the calculation 10 * 256 + 99 = 2659.

Comment: @Fayaz: any pocket calculator will confirm.

Comment: Its not about the result of the calculation. What I didn't get is why we are multiplying 10 with 256 and adding 99. I understand 10 is the value of the variable and 99 is the ascii value of c. How you put them together is I didn't get.

Comment: @Fayaz because they were put togetehr in same segment.. when you had read that address, you had read larger storage that encompasses both variables, resulting value is value of their binary representation for LITTLE_ENDIAN CPUs. It depends on compiler and CPU architecture if this would happen or not. In general this is UB, you may as well cause a segfault

Answer (score 0):

You're violating strict aliasing rules.  Since `p3` is ultimately pointing to a `char`, you can't `static_cast` to an `int*` and get reliable results.  What *should* work is if you `static_cast` to a `char *` (the actual type `p3` is pointing to):

```
    cout<<"Content of address in p2/p3:"<< *(static_cast<char *>(p3))<<endl;
```

Comment: I know I am not doing the right thing. Basically, I am learning pointers. I coudn't figure out the logic why the output is consistent when an int variable is defined somewhere above.

Comment: I have already mentioned that I am expecting junk values. My question is why it is not junk

Comment: This is a typical non-explanation of undefined behavior.

Comment: It's consistent output because the program happens to lay out memory that way.  Assuming a 4-byte `int`, you're going to read 3 bytes into whatever comes after `c2`; it happens to be `x` in your case, but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: Actually there are few options for a compiler. Allocating the variables sequentially, by increasing addresses, as they are declared is a pretty natural/unavoidable way. The value could be junk on a big endian machine.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - Is that guaranteed or just the typical implementation? I ask because with optimizations I'd expect the compiler to completely remove `x` and `p` (Godbolt seems to confirm this: https://godbolt.org/g/CQHVZt).

Comment: @StephenNewell Not at all guaranteed, C++ makes no claim about storage. But common sense does.